# computational Complexity of recursion

Tags: performance, recursion, time-complexity

I have program like this on labs

```
int fun( int n )
{
    if (n==0) return 0;
    else return fun(n-1) +1;
}
```

And professor say that function is O(2^n).
I Can't understand why, every time I count O I get O(n)

Anybody can explain it to me ?

Comment: it is O(n)...your prof is wrong LOL...which university btw?

Comment: now, there is a simple way to verify who is right, for simple questions like this you can just sub in some numbers and count the # of operations, O(2^n) means it will always be greater than c*2^n. in this example c cannot be < 1 so if you sub in 10 you can see it is clearly not the case

Comment: Well "like this" may be dangerous. What problem do you solve with that recursion method? (of course, in this method, you are right, it is O(n)).

Comment: @libik by like this i mean something can be easily counted

Comment: I doubt your professor thinks this code solves the tower of hanoi. It clearly does not. It solves the problem "needlessly count from n to zero".

Comment: @Steve I try and Get O(n). But I still not sure. Can you use mat to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int fun( int n )
{
    if (n==0) return 0; //1 operation for the base case
    else return fun(n-1) +1; //n-1 operation in total
}
```

we can look at it backward, lets say you are at the base case now, you will do one `return 0;` which is O(1), and then one level up you will `return 0+1;` which is also O(1). How many times are you going to return? well the answer is simple, n times, so n*1 = n => O(n). if you want to be exact, you are doing one comparison, one addition and one return each time you recurce, so that makes it 3*n - 1 in total which is still O(n)